# In Spark-Scala, how to copy Array of Lists into DataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am familiar with Python and I am learning Spark-Scala.

I want to build a DataFrame which has structure desribed by this syntax:

```
// Prepare training data from a list of (label, features) tuples.
val training = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (1.1, Vectors.dense(1.1, 0.1)),
  (0.2, Vectors.dense(1.0, -1.0)),
  (3.0, Vectors.dense(1.3, 1.0)),
  (1.0, Vectors.dense(1.2, -0.5))
)).toDF("label", "features")
```

I got the above syntax from this URL:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html

Currently my data is in array which I had pulled out of a DF:

```
val my_a = gspc17_df.collect().map{row => Seq(row(2),Vectors.dense(row(3).asInstanceOf[Double],row(4).asInstanceOf[Double]))}
```

The structure of my array is very similar to the above DF:

```
my_a: Array[Seq[Any]] =
Array(
  List(-1.4830674013266898, [-0.004192832940431825,-0.003170667657263393]),
  List(-0.05876766500768526, [-0.008462913654529357,-0.006880595828929472]),
  List(1.0109273250546658, [-3.1816797620416693E-4,-0.006502619326182358]))
```

How to copy data from my array into a DataFrame which has the above structure?

I tried this syntax:

```
val my_df = spark.createDataFrame(my_a).toDF("label","features")
```

Spark barked at me:

```
<console>:105: error: inferred type arguments [Seq[Any]] do not conform to method createDataFrame's type parameter bounds [A <: Product]
       val my_df = spark.createDataFrame(my_a).toDF("label","features")
                         ^
<console>:105: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Seq[Any]]
 required: Seq[A]
       val my_df = spark.createDataFrame(my_a).toDF("label","features")
                                         ^
scala>
```

Answer (score 4):

The first problem here is that you use `List` to store row data. List is a homogeneous data structure and since the only common type for `Any` (`row(2)`) and `DenseVector` is `Any` (`Object`) you end up with a `Seq[Any]`.

The next issue is that you use `row(2)` at all. Since `Row` is effectively a collection of `Any` this operation doesn't return any useful type and result couldn't be stored in a `DataFrame` without providing an explicit `Encoder`.

From the more Sparkish perspective it is not the good approach neither. `collect`-int just to transform data shouldn't require any comment and. mapping over `Rows` just to create `Vectors` doesn't make much sense either.

Assuming that there is no type mismatch you can use `VectorAssembler`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array(df.columns(3), df.columns(4)))
  .setOutputCol("features")

assembler.transform(df).select(df.columns(2), "features")
```

or if you really want to handle this manually an `UDF`.

```
val toVec = udf((x: Double, y: Double) => Vectors.dense(x, y))

df.select(col(df.columns(2)), toVec(col(df.columns(3)), col(df.columns(4))))
```

In general I would strongly recommend getting familiar with Scala before you start using it with Spark.